# Working with uninitialized variables in functions?

Tags: function

We're tasked to create a change converter using a function. We're asked to declare the following variables uninitialized:

```
// Declare variables amount (amount in cents), count25 (quantity of quarters), count10 (quantity of dimes),
// count5 (quantity of nickels), count1 (quantity of pennies), and count (quantity of coins) to hold whole values
int amount;
int count25;
int count10;
int count5;
int count1;
int count;
```

We're then asked to create a function coinChanger() to return the quantity of each coin that we'll need, along with the total number of coins. My function is as follows:

```
  // Calculate the quantity of each type of coin and the total number of coins that are needed to provide a given change
// and return all these values along with the total number of coins that are needed for the change
void coinChanger(int &amount, int &count25, int &count10, int &count05, int &count01, int &count)
{
    count25 = (amount / 25);
    amount = (amount % 25);
    count10 = (amount / 10);
    amount = (amount % 10);
    count05 = (amount / 5);
    amount = (amount % 5);
    count01 = (amount / 1);
    count = count25 + count10 + count05 + count01;

    return 0; }
```

However, whenever I call the function coinChanger and input each variable like this: `coinChanger(amount, count25, count10, count5, count1, count);`

I get that all of the variables included (except for amount because it was assigned a value by the user, earlier in the program) are "uninitialized local variables". I realize one would say it's because the variables are being uninitialized, but they're all assigned in my function, so I don't know why it isn't working.

I saw my instructor today and he said it ought to work. I'm stumped. I know I have a gargantuan question, but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Stating the language you are using would help draw people qualified to answer your question. As a front-end / js develeoper I see this function only ever returning the number zero because it ends ```return 0;``` but I dont know if this is incorrect because the language isnt stated.

Comment: I did not see the error you're mentioning, but I had to apply a lot of guesswork about the things you didn't include in the post (like a complete file or a compilation command) so we're debugging two different examples. Maybe you can create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and verify that everything is included by copy-pasting from your own post into a new file and seeing that it still gives the same error